# I Forgot CMOS administrator password

Tags: cmos

Hi I forgot my admin password for a probook 450 g1 . I have removed the hard drive and CMOS battery and still asking for a administrator password

Comment: You are very most likely out of luck.  Contact HP Support

Comment: On most modern devices it’s not possible to reset the CMOS password. The CMOS password is independent of any storage device

Comment: If your laptop is not too recent, enter a wrong password 3 times, which will get you a code that you can enter on https://bios-pw.org/ to get back a password that will work.

Comment: The "not too recent" above means something from 2012 or older.